# Applying Javascript Only Below a Certain Width

Tags: javascript

I have a search form that I use a simple bit of JS on to toggle its display when a button is clicked.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="form-search">
  <form action="/search" method="post" role="search">
    <label for="searchbox">Search</label>
    <input value="" name="searchquery" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search Site" type="text">
    <button aria-label="Submit Search" type="submit" tabindex="-1">
      <img src="/i/misc/searchbutton.gif" alt="Submit Search">
    </button>
  </form>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('form-search');"><img src="search-toggle.gif" /></a>
```

And the JS:

```
<script>
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block')
  e.style.display = 'none';
else
  e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>
```

Note: I got the JS from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/showhide-element/.

What I would like to do is *only* have this script work on window widths of 984px or narrower. I think the logic would go something like: "if the window width <= 984px AND display = block, change to display = none", but I'm not sure how to stipulate two "ifs" in JS.

So, first question: how do I stipulate both if conditions in my JS?

Then, I will need to "reset" the display to inline for window widths over 984px, so if someone resizes their window the search form will always display, even if they had hidden it with the JS at a narrower width.

Second question: is there a way to say in the JS "when screen is resized to >984px, set display = inline"?

Thanks so much for any recommendations! I'm new to JS. :)

Edited for what I ended up with, thanks to the answer from squgeim:

```
<script>
<!--
var WIDTH_LIMIT = 984;
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);

  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

  if(e.style.display == 'block' && windowWidth <= WIDTH_LIMIT) {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
  var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var e = document.getElementById('form-search');
  if (currentWidth > WIDTH_LIMIT) {
    e.style.display = 'inline'
  } else {
      e.style.display = 'none';
  }

});
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: try using [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth)

Comment: Why am I only allowed to "close" the search if my window is at most 984px wide? O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.innerWidth` to find out the current width of the window.

So your function will be something like:

```
var WIDTH_LIMIT = 984;
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);

  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

  if(e.style.display == 'block' && windowWidth <= WIDTH_LIMIT) {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Now, to check if the window has been resized to the permitted limit, you can use an event listener to the `window`'s `resize` event.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
  var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (currentWidth >= WIDTH_LIMIT) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked! I edited my post above to show how I adapted your code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth) to get the screen width, this way:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var screen_width = window.innerWidth;
    if(screen_width <= 984) {
        // Screen is smaller than (or equal to) 984px
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    else {
        // do something if it's larger
    }
}
```

About conditions and operators you can [learn on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/herinuquti/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question (multiple conditions):

You can chain conditions within one if/else statement. For example:

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = "World";
var c = "Test";

if(a === b && c === "Test"){
    alert("both conditions are true");
} else {
    alert("One or both of the conditions don't ");
}
```

So `&&` means **"This and this"**, while `||` means **"This or this"**.

And regarding your second question, have a look here: [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)